# Separate drawing from updating in XNA

Tags: c#, xna

So, I'm making an XNA game for a class at my school. I'd like to set the update rate to 30 times per second, which I've done using `this.TargetElapsedTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0 / 30.0);` in my game class. However, this also limits the framerate to 30fps. I've set up my drawing so that it interpolates the location and rotation of everything being drawn, so that it can draw multiple times every update and smooth the values between the updates. How do I tell the game to unlock the framerate, but still keep the update rate at 30 updates per second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are performing update logic inside the Draw loop (the location and rotation interpolation), but the Draw loop doesn't care; all it knows is that Game.Update was not called and so it doesn't have to bother drawing/redrawing anything.

Instead of setting the TargetElapsedTime like you are: in the Update loop, manually keep track of how much time has passed since the last update to determine whether or not you want to run update code.

Here is some code in case it helps to see. (Sorry for the formatting issues)

1. Don't set Game.TargetElapsedTime.
2. Instantiate a new [GameTimer](https://github.com/Foosersoft/C4/blob/master/Library/C4.Xna/GameTimer.cs) using your TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0 / 30.0) in the constructor.
3. Assign an event handler to handle the GameTimer.Tick event.  Your interpolation logic can go in Game.Update, but any other update logic can be thrown in the Tick event handler so that it obeys the TimeSpan you've specified.
4. Remember to add the GameTimer object to Game.Components so that it participates in the Game's Update loop otherwise Tick will never fire.

Comment: Thanks! Worked great :D